# Gson: How to write Deserializer for Linked Objects

Tags: java, json, gson

Imagine the following JSON for a book Library:

```
{
    "books": [{
            "id": 562,
            "name": "This is a booktitle"
        },
        {
            "id": 875,
            "name": "This is another booktitle"
        }
    ]
}
```

To get more information about the first book I can simply put up a request `https://thislibrarydoesnotexists.com/books/562` which would return the following JSON:

```
{
    "name": "This is a booktitle",
    "pages": 137,
    "blurp": "This book is about the booktitle",
    "authors": [{
        "name": "Generic Author",
        "id": 78
    }]
}
```

Now I could request more information about the author using the request `https://thislibrarydoesnotexists.com/authors/78` and this game would go on for quite a while until I got all the information.

Now my goal is it to have the following java class structure:

```
class Library{
    List<Book> books
}

class Book{
    String name;
    int pages;
    String blurp;
    List<Author> authors;
}

class Author{...}
```

But how to write the custom deserializer for that? This is my best attempt so far:

```
final Gson defaultGson = new GsonBuilder.create();
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();    
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Book.class, new JsonDeserializer<Book>() {

    @Override
    public Skill deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                    throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        if(jsonObject.has("id")) { //It is just a link to a book
            String bookJson = getJson("https://thislibrarydoesnotexists.com/books/" + jsonObject.get("id").getAsInt());
            Book book = gson.fromJson(bookJson, Book.class);
            return book;
        }else { 
            Book book = defaultGson.fromJson(json, Book.class); //#1
            return book;
        }
    }


}); 
gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

This solution fails at #1 since the custom deserializer for the Authors wouldn't get used.

What is the right way to solve this problem?

- Create the Book object manually in the else case? //Lot of work for a complex API
- Use multiple Gsons with some kind of Gson hierarchy? //Ugly and won't work when having cyclic dependencies
- Use a wrapper class? //Just ugly but should work

Answer (score 0):

Change `List<Book> books` to `List<BookSummary> books`, because the object returned for a single book is not the same object returned in a list of books.

```
class BookSummary {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

is not the same as

```
class BookDetail {
    String name;
    int pages;
    String blurp;
    List<Author> authors;
}
```

No need for a (de)serializer.

Comment: Yes, this is what a Gson generator outputs too. I totally get that a "BookSummary" is something different than a "BookDetail" and that in theory, I would need two classes. But this is why I put up this question: I want to achieve the given class structure as written in the question. I want to iterate through the library multiple times to find books meeting specific conditions. Putting up a new HTTP request each time isn't just super slow. I also get blocked from the API due to spamming. This is why I want a local copy of the whole library which allows me to easily loop through its objects.

Comment: @Crigges If you want the list to return book details, so the client doesn't have to come back for the details, then change the server to do so, but that is not what is showed in the question. The question shows that only summary information is returned in the list, so the client has to query for the details. Your comment makes no sense, in context of the question.

Comment: The API is given I can't change it

Comment: @Crigges Then I really don't understand your comment. If the server's list response don't contain the data (e.g. `pages`, `authors`, ...), then you *have to* make the other calls to get the detail. You can't just invent the data out of thin air, so I don't understand what you're saying. You get a list of summaries from the server. For those books where you need more detail, you can ask the server for it.

Comment: @Crigges You can *cache* the detail information if needed, but the only way to get  a *"local copy of the whole library"* is to make all the calls for the individual books. Trying to download the whole library that way will certainly get you marked as a spammer. Don't attempt to download the whole library. Download the details *as they are needed*, and cache them. The keyword here is **cache**. There are many great articles on the web about caching, so you should start research that.

Comment: Yes, this would be possible. I could create two classes and create a getter to get the BookDetail in from the BookSummary object, and then cache the object to limit the requests. I just thought it would be nicer to have this class structure since a BookSummary is pretty useless if I want to have the BookDetail anyway.

Comment: Yes, I get already marked as spammer after a few hundreds of requests. This is why I want a local copy that I can just serialize. If creating this copy takes several weeks of runtime that doesn't matter. For this copy I want this nice class layout since the id reference is only useful anyway when using the original API.